# A better wording for "of which" in this context

Tags: word-choice

What would be a different choice for the words "of which" in the following sentence (such that the original meaning would remain the same)?

> However, this working hypothesis was been proven to be fundamentally
> wrong by the work published by (someone), **of which** major results include
> the following: ...

Comment: Why do you think there needs to be a better version? The hypothesis was proved wrong by X's work. The results of this work include... The use of _of which_ is perfectly normal here.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest... it just felt like it's not "exactly" right for it, but since you think it's fine I'll change my question to "are there any other fitting choices"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KateBunting has stated, "The use of **of which** is perfectly normal here".

However, your text can be improved:

> However, this working hypothesis **has/had** been proven to be fundamentally wrong by the work published by (someone), of which **the** major results include the following: ...

It is also possible to say:

> ... the major results of which include...

Comment: True about the mistake (it's more of a typo though) - thanks for the correction!

Comment: Thanks. I like the 2nd option you presented.